# Как передать контекст через Bundle

Tags: android

Мне нужно передать мою `Activity`, то есть `Context`, через `Bundle`. Как ее туда "засунуть"?

Comment: контекст нельзя передать через `Bundle`. Если вам это понадобилось, то вы все делаете неправильно. Кажется мы уже договаривались, что вы не будете плодить вопросы с "идеологически" неверными подходами, которые сами придумываете, а вместо этого будете спрашивать о самой проблеме.

Comment: если у вас двже получится это сделать, вы всеравно не сможете воспользоваться контекстом. Вы явно пытаетесь сделать какой-то ужасный костыль. Лучше спросите то, чего вы пытаетесь достичь, а не то, как реализовать ваш костыль.

Comment: @metalurgus, да проблема в том, чтобы описать всю проблему, нужно скинуть пол проекта. Но все-таки это я был тормозом и не заметил одну ошибку, из-за чего пытался запустить программу костылем, но когда писал костыль не заметил еще одну ошибку (для чего и хотел закинуть `Activity` через `Bundle`). Но потом я все-таки дописал костыль! Правда забыл инициализировать контекст и у меня выдавало NPE. В поисках ошибки я понял, что получилась хрень, начал писать все сначала — получилось все аккуратно и чисто (даже без костылей :)).

Comment: @metalurgus,  Оказалось переменную нужно регистрировать не через `getActivity().registerForContextMenu`, a просто registerForContextMenu`, но вызывать контекстное меню нужно было через `getActivity.openContextMenu` (из-за чего я и запутался). Теперь все хорошо! Чувствую Юрий, pavlofff, Вы и еще многие будут очень рады, когда я допишу это приложение и все-таки прочитаю книгу :D.

Comment: @pavlofff, сообщения выше и Вам тоже (просто не смог сразу двум отправить).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Никак**. `Bundle` предназначен для хранения сериализующихся данных в форме ключ-значение.

Опишите зачем вам это надо и мы вам скажем как надо делать. Варианты могут быть такими:

1. Передать `Context` через метод/конструктор.
2. Получить `Context`методом `View.getContext()` любого виджета.
3. У фрагмента можно методом `getActivity()`.
4. Можно сделать синглтон класса `Application` и получать его `Context`.
5. В случае коммуникации активити-сервис используйте `Binder`

Comment: А что, активити не может быть значением? Не сериализуется?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, ну, в терминах я не силён, но, насколько я понимаю активити - это процесс, засим его и не этого... не сохранить как набор данных... Если в чём-то я не прав - поправьте в комментах или сам ответ)

Comment: @NickVolynkin О возможности передавать активити(контекст) через бандл не стоит даже задумываться, это не только за гранью зла, но и вообще не в этой вселенной.

Comment: Проблему я решил, но чисто теоретически, можно как-то `Context` переделать в тип данных типа `int`, `string` и тому подобное, а потом обратно? (Типы данных привел ИСКЛЮЧИТЕЛЬНО для примера).

Answer (score 0):

**Как вариант, можно доставать контекст приложения:**

```
import android.content.Context;


public class ApplicationContext { 
private static Context context;

public static Context getAppContext() {
    return ApplicationContext.context;
}

public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    ApplicationContext.context = getApplicationContext();
}
}
```

И в манифесте в блоке `<application` дописываем `android:name=".ApplicationContext"`

А вызываем этот контекст так:

```
ApplicationContext.getAppContext()
```

**А если Вы во фрагмент хотите контекст активити**, то можно так:

```
private AppCompatActivity act;    

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    act = (AppCompatActivity) context;
}
```